# Полиморфизм в Java и перегрузка

Tags: java

Относиться ли перегрузка метода к полиморфизму в языке Java? Как я знаю только переопределение метода относиться к полиморфизму в языке Java, а перегрузка нет

Comment: IMHO, это вопрос терминологический, если не сказать философский, и практическое значение может иметь разве что при прохождении интервью. Буду признателен, если более умудренные коллеги объяснят, что я не прав.

Comment: @m.vokhm да вот ходил на 2 собеседования, на 1 сказали является, на 2 сказали не является, я вот сижу и думаю

Comment: Читай тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849435/204920. Поэтому перегрузка не имеет ничего общего с полиморфизмом.

Answer (score 5):

Понятие полиморфизма ввёл в компьютерные науки Кристофер Стрэчи в статье 1967-го года. Вначале он рассматривал математические операторы, которые умеют работать с данными разных типов, например, оператор плюс. От операторов он перешёл к функциям, которые также могут обрабатывать данные разных типов.

Если следовать этому — классическому — определению, то перегрузка как раз и позволяет создавать полиморфную функцию, с единственным именем, но разными типами параметров.

Этот вид полиморфизма технически отличается от виртуальных функций, но только технически. По сути это тот же полиморфизм, по крайней мере, в терминологии Стрэчи. Виртуальная функция в первом параметре неявно получает ссылку на объект (`this`). Страустрап описывает этот механизм в своей книге по C++. Он же (механизм) применяется и в JVM, и в .NET. Получается, что виртуальный метод полиморфен потому, что может работать с разными типами своего неявного первого параметра.

Перегрузка относится к так называемому ad hoc полиморфизму. Это название означает, что нам нужно писать разные версии функции для разных типов.

Другой вид полиморфизма — параметрический, характерный для обобщённого программирования (generic programming). Метод `List<T>.add` умеет добавлять в список данные разных типов, и его код вы пишите всего один раз.

Итого, получается, что в Java полиморфизм, описанный Стрэчи доступен посредством:

1. Виртуальных функций.
2. Перегрузки функций.
3. Обобщённых функций.

Первые два способа — ad hoc полиморфизм, последний — параметрический полиморфизм.

**UPDATE**

Поискал старую статью Стрэчи в интернете, не нашёл. Есть поздняя статья 2000-го года за его же авторством: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.332.3161&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Не относится. Перегрузка осуществляется в рамках одного класса путём определения разного количества аргументов и разного типа аргументов.

Comment: Если я всё правильно понимаю, то суть полиморфизма в том, что мы можем в наследниках переопределять методы родителя. Но так, что, если мы создаём объекты класса не через дочерний конструктор, а через родительский, то, вызвав эти методы, мы получим результаты, определенные в детях, хотя вызывали что-то вроде `parent.doSomething()`, а не `child.doSomething()`. Я не сильный джавист, рекомендую Эккеля к прочтению.

Answer (score 1):

Хотя, как отметили в другом ответе, с чисто теоретической точки зрения перегрузку можно отнести к некоторой разновидности полиморфизма, в практическом программировании перегрузка полиморфизмом не является. В языках, допускающих перегрузку, реальное имя функции состоит из двух частей - собственно имени, которое задает пользователь, и части, которую генерирует компилятор, и которая описывает параметры функции. Так что перегруженные функции - это совершенно разные функции с разными именами.

Единственное отличие перегруженных функций от обычных - это то, что может возникнуть неоднозначность при вызове, когда аргументы могут приводиться к параметрам нескольких функций. Но это все же не полиморфизм, потому что такие неоднозначности разрешаются на этапе компиляции, а полиморфизм относится прежде всего к этапу выполнения.